# Why is admin logging me out?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, cookie

I go to the admin login in Chrome after clearing all cookies and everything.  First thing I check Chrome cookies. I see only one cookie.

**Name: adminhtml**

**Domain: .mysite.com**

**Path: /**

**Created: Tuesday, May 24, 2016 at 2:22:00 PM**

**Expires: Wednesday, May 24, 2017 at 2:22:00 PM** (a year from today).

Under Configuration/Advanced/Admin/Security/

**Session Lifetime (seconds) =31536000**

In phpinfo it says:

**session.cookie_lifetime   86400**

**session.gc_maxlifetime    86400**

In index.php I have this:

**ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '31536000');**

**ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '31536000');**

TIME SETTINGS:

**GMT: 18:22:00**

**Local time: 02:22:00 pm**

In .htaccess this: **php_value date.timezone 'America/New_York'**

New York time: **2:22 PM**

Server time America/Phoenix: **11:22 AM**

How come it logs me off? Looks like it should at least last one day.

BTW What is the difference in Sessions and Cookies?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question: is that happening just in Chrome? Are you able to login and the system is logging you out before one day, or are you not even logging in?

Comment: Cookies are files saved in the browser, which means that the user can edit or delete it. Session is a virtual storage, there is no file on the user's browser and the user don't have control over it. [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339783/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-and-cookies-in-php)

Comment: Session values are usually reset after a period of time has passed without a connection from the client with which the session is associated.

Cookie values are saved until their expiry time or the browser is closed if one isn't set